# Temporal change in variable - lag () function not grouping

Tags: r, dplyr, panel-data

As I am currently working with panel data I would like to create a variable that tracks the age difference over time.

```
id    Date          Age
3     2018/11/29     30
3     2019/08/22     30
4     2018/01/11     45
7     2019/02/14     40
7     2019/02/17     40
7     2019/09/23     41 
7     2019/10/29     41
```

I tried to do this by:

```
df %>%
  arrange(id, date) %>%
  group_by(id)
  mutate(
    age_change = age - lag(age),
    age_increases = age_change > 1,
    age_decreases = age_change < 0
    )
```

The issue is that the new variables are not actually grouped by id, i.e., the lag change is based on the previous age regardless of its id:

```
id    date          age     age_change
3     2018/11/29     30            NA
3     2019/08/22     30             0
4     2018/01/11     45             5
7     2019/02/14     40            -5
7     2019/02/17     40             0
7     2019/09/23     41             1
7     2019/10/29     41             0
```

Any ideas on how to solve this? I have already tried the age_change = age - lag(age, order_by=id) and using dplyr::lag as suggested in other threads but to no avail.
Thanks.

Comment: Your code works for me. Maybe you have other conflicts that are causing an issue with grouping.

Comment: @AndS. Is right, maybe closing and restarting you  R session will solve the error. Also, in `age_increases = age_change > 1`, isn't a positive value (`age_change > 0`) an increase?